# If a moderator reviewed my flag, how was it disputed?

Tags: support, bug, flag-history, disputed-flags

I saw the following in my flag list today:

[image]

Huh? This doesn't make sense. The only way a flag like this can be disputed is by being reviewed by a 10k+ non-moderator. However, if that is the case, then why does it say that a moderator reviewed it?

Comment: Why do you say that this can only be done by a "10k non-moderator"?

Comment: @Werner I know that the second case is if the flag is "very low quality" and the post is edited, but this was not a VLQ flag...

Comment: @gparyani: This does not make sense. What "second case"? You only show "duplicate" and "not an answer" flags in the screen capture.

Comment: @Werner There are two ways a flag can be disputed: if a 10k+ non-moderator flags it as invalid, or if the flag is "very low quality" and the post is edited.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: User1 disputed your flag. Moderator2 reviewed it. They are probably not the same person.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flags are dismissed as helpful or declined by a moderator; they are marked disputed if a community member disagrees with the flag.  So in this particular case, not only did a moderator disagree with the flag, but one or more community members also disagreed with the flag.